# Wordpress url not return properly

Tags: wordpress

I have a site let's say example.com. When I try to load the site, all the assets and other urls avoiding parent folder. `https://example.com/example/`, this is my home page. When I tried to load admin, `https://example.com/example/wp-login.php`, it will redirect to `https://example.com/wp-login.php`. All other urls, and assets urls have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Change your site address in Wordpress Admin Panel:  Settings > General > Site Address

Comment: I couldn't access admin panel, same url problem. I have changed the site address in wp_options table, but no use

Comment: Do you have any .htaccess rule that could force the redirect?

Comment: I found the problem, site url is defined in wp-config.php and it is not correct. I changed the url and now it's working